# Why doesn't my textbox show over my canvas element?

Tags: javascript, html, raphael

I'd like to use Raphael.js and create some nice diagrams / SVG graphics for my site. I want users to be able to enter text content which would normally be via a `<input type="text">` element in normal html.

Is there anyway that I can use this element **on top of a `<canvas>` element**, so that I can have my user enter text that way, or do I have to roll my own by listening for keystrokes and painting the characters onto the element?

**Rephrasing Question**

Why can't I see the text field if I do this:

```
<canvas style="background-color:blue;height:100px;width:100px>
    <input type="text" style="background-color:white;z-index:101" />
</canvas>
```

and if this is not possible, what are the alternatives?

Many thanks

Answer (score 4):

There needs to be some way to fallback to alternative content (like a static image or a text "Get a browser with canvas support") for older browsers that do not understand the canvas element. The children of the canvas element are designated for that purpose.

You can, however, position the input over the canvas with [`position:absolute`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#choose-position) (relative, or static):

```
<canvas style="background-color:blue;height:100px;width:100px">
</canvas>
<input type="text" style="z-index:101; position:absolute; top:10px; left:10px;"/>
```

[Here's a live demo](http://phihag.de/2011/so/canvas-textinput.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm suprised that there isn't more info on this sort of thing out there because I would have thought that a lot of people would want to do the same thing.